# SVG is not displayed after DOM Element detached

Tags: javascript, svg, shadow-dom

I have a collection view. And i manipulate items while they are detached.
So common workflow looks something like this:

All Icons looks like this

`<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="img/icons.svg#trash"></use></svg>`

Detach or Remove all items:

```
_.forOwn(this._v, function (view, key, _v) {
    view.detach();
    if (!collection.get(key)) {
        delete _v[key];
    }
});
```

Append existing or create new item.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
this.collection.each(function (model) {
    var item;
    if (view._v.hasOwnProperty(model.cid)) {
        item = view._v[model.cid];
    } else if (!isFiltered || (isFiltered && view.collectionFilter(model))) {
        item = view._v[model.cid] = $(view.itemTemplate(model.toJSON()));
    }
    frag.appendChild(item[0]);
});
this.container.html(frag);
```

But after. I reviece strange picture: Icons displayed only on newly created items. But on others they don't.

I guess this is because #shadow content is not reloaded. I see that SVG displayed within shadow DOM.
Does anybody know how to fix this? Reload shadow part manually for example?

Comment: Could you please create a (runnable) example for this?

Comment: Need some time to isolate code. But i make it soon. Still need to work

Comment: I suspect you are recreating elements in the html namespace rather than the SVG namespace which is where they would need to be to be functional.